# postgresql if not exist reports syntax error "IF"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I was trying to create database and tables with commands:

```
\i 'D:/Project/data/Create database tables.sql';
```

But it reports syntax error "IF".

I searched for solutions. Some mentioned that adding `DO $do$ BEGIN` and `END $$` will work. But it reports an error as well  `ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$do$`

I'm not familiar with sql language. May I ask how to successfully create database and tables using the script. Thanks.

Below is `create database and table` sql script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '[abc]')
  BEGIN 
    CREATE DATABASE [abc]   
    END 
    GO  
    
    USE [abc]
    GO  

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DEMOGRAPHICS]    ************/


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DEMOGRAPHICS](
    [caseid] [bigint] NULL,
    [primaryid] [bigint] NULL,
    [caseversion] [int] NULL,
    [fda_dt] [int] NULL,
    [I_F_COD] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [event_dt] [int] NULL,
    [AGE] [float] NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [COUNTRY_CODE] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [Period] [varchar](4) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: That code is so far from being standard SQL or PostgreSQL specific, that I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi. I understand your concern. It does not look the same as postgresql script I previously used. But it looks very similar. I also find a link here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109173/demographics-dimension-table-finding-the-key which might be the same script pattern. The code I pasted here is the original code. In their original article, they stated they used sql server 2019 to create the dataset. I don't know how this script works. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's easier if you installed SQL Server

Comment: Sorry, that looks nothing like a Postgres script. Provide the actual Postgres script you actually used previously as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your reply. I successfully create databases before for several times using postgresql. But I noticed this script indeed looks different. I've sent email to the authors. Maybe they can tell what kind of script it realy is.

Comment: It is a SQL Server script as the question you linked to indicated. Also `[]` for identifier quoting is Sybase/SQL Server specific AFAIK. Also` sys.databases` is a SQL Server thing. Bottom line this script will not work on Postgres.